# Dual boot multiple copys of the same version of windows without an install Cd

Tags: windows, boot, multi-boot

I have a HP 245 laptop that has come with Windows 8.1 preinstalled.  I need to create a dual boot with the same version of windows so I can use different versions of office.  This computer doesn't have an install CD but rather a recovery partion. Because it's the same computer, Can I use the same product key? I think I can download an Windows iso from microsoft to create my own install disk but how do I find out the exact version? How should I go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

To dual boot, you need to install two operating systems. The recovery DVD/partition can only be used to recover an existing installation. You can't install a full OS from a recovery partition.

Microsoft Office versions install in different folders:

- 2007 installs in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office12`
- 2010 installs in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office14`
- 2013 installs in `C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office15`

You can run multiple office versions on the same OS.